# Neo4j APOC group a subset of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a bunch of nodes like `test {myGroupIs:2}` and some of them have a relation with an other kind of nodes : `others {some stuff}`. 
I can group those nodes using `myGroupIs` as follow : `CALL apoc.nodes.group(['test','others'], ['myGroupIs']) YIELD node, relationship RETURN *`

Now I want to get the nodes with 'myGroupIs = 2' grouped and with link to `others` nodes, I found this way to do it : `CALL apoc.nodes.group(['test','others'], ['myGroupIs'], null, { filter: {`test.myGroupIs.min`:2,`test.myGroupIs.max`:2}}) YIELD node, relationship RETURN *`
This is dirty but I don't know how to to the same in another way.

Now I'm blocked because I want to do the same but with 'myGroupIs = 2 OR myGroupIs = 3'..
It seems impossible to perform apoc.nodes.group on query result (like a Match where ..) so I don't know how to do.

I thought to perform a Match() where query and create temporary nodes with specific labels but I don't think it's the right way.

How can I do ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Doing `myGroupIs = 2 OR myGroupIs = 3` is easy, since 2 and 3 are contiguous integers. You just need to change the filter's `test.myGroupIs.max` value to 3:

```
CALL apoc.nodes.group(
  ['test', 'others'], ['myGroupIs'], null,
  {filter: {`test.myGroupIs.min`:2, `test.myGroupIs.max`:3}}
) YIELD node, relationship
RETURN *
```